# Lista ativa a outra em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando fazer funcionar uma lista, que se caso uma opção no primeiro "select box" estiver selecionada, o outro "select box" aparece tal opção. Mas não está funcionando.

A principios os códigos estão certos.
Alguem consegue me dizer oque está acontecendo?

Segue o código

Primeiro Select Box:

```
<select id="eassociado" name="eassociado" required>
 <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione uma opção -- </option>
  <option class="lista">ABRAPP</option>
  <option class="lista">ABAAI</option>
  <option class="lista">IBGC</option>
  <option class="lista">ABRACAM</option>
  <option class="lista">ABBC</option>

 </select>
```

Segundo Select Box

```
        <select name="ingresso" id="chkveg" required>

        <option  class="associadoEntidade" value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQLB9m">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras + C.Dados = R$940,00</option>

        <option  class="associadoEntidade" value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQZk-m">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras Normal = R$1.125,00</option>

        </select>
```

Javascript:

```
    var lista = document.querySelectorAll(".lista");

var associadoEntidade = document.querySelectorAll(".associadoEntidade");
console.log(associadoEntidade);

for(var i = 0; i < associadoEntidade.length; i++){

       associadoEntidade[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }

if (lista.selected==true){

        associadoEntidade[i].style.display = "block"; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isto com o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var eassociado = document.getElementById('eassociado');
var chkveg = document.getElementById('chkveg');

chkveg.style.display = 'none';

eassociado.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var escolhido = eassociado.options[eassociado.selectedIndex].index;
  
  
  if(escolhido == 1) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    var um = chkveg.selectedIndex = 0;
    chkveg.options[1].style.display = 'none';
  }
  else if(escolhido == 2) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
    var dois = chkveg.selectedIndex = 1;
    chkveg.options[0].style.display = 'none';
  } // Asssim por diante
  else chkveg.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<select id="eassociado" name="eassociado" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione uma opção -- </option>
  <option class="lista">ABRAPP</option>
  <option class="lista">ABAAI</option>
  <option class="lista">IBGC</option>
  <option class="lista">ABRACAM</option>
  <option class="lista">ABBC</option>
</select>

<select name="ingresso" id="chkveg" required>
  <option class="associadoEntidade" value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQLB9m">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras + C.Dados = R$940,00</option>
  <option class="associadoEntidade" value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQZk-m">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras Normal = R$1.125,00</option>
</select>
```

Comment: oi amigao, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas nao eh muito bem isso que eu preciso, eu gostaria de que quando IBGC(por exemplo) for selecionado na primeira droplist, o Associados Entidades Apoia..... que fica no segundo campo aparecesse. E assim com os demais, entende?

Comment: Entendi, mas, qual seria a relação disso, pois no primeiro select tem **6 options** e no segundo tem 2, qual seria a relação?

Comment: eu coloquei só 2 aqui pra entender melhor, mas no meu código tem mais

Comment: Editei a resposta, fazendo um exemplo básico, fazendo cada verificação.

Comment: é mais ou menos isso, mas como eu escondo uma ou mais opção do segundo select?

Comment: A cara então você não quer um select, já viu algum select com apenas uma opção??!

Comment: quero tipo assim, (por exemplo) se eu selecionar ABRAPP, esconde Associados Entidades Apoiadoras Normal = R$1.125,00, sei que tem q colocar algo dentro do if do seu código, mas nao to sabendo oq

Comment: Vc já tentou explicar várias vezes o que quer e eu cada vez entendo menos, lá em cima na pergunta vc diz **que se caso uma opção no primeiro "select box" estiver selecionada, o outro "select box" aparece tal opção** agora vc já quer que esconda. Não compriendo o que realmente quer fazer.

Comment: sim, eu reformulei a pergunta de um jeito meio errado, mas por exemplo que vc escreveu, vi que é mais facil esconder usando algum código dentro desse if

Comment: tentei   if(escolhido == 1) {
    chkveg.style.display = 'inline-block';
 var um = chkveg.selectedIndex = 1;
 um.style.display = 'none';
  }

mas retorna variavel anonima

Comment: Acho que entendi o que queria, editei a resposta.

Comment: Show, deu certo, o código ficou enorme, acho que daria pra reduzir bastante se eu entendesse mais de js, https://jsfiddle.net/ves2b5ag/1/

Comment: É que o correto é fazer um **`for`** e ao invés de pegar os options por numero pegar pelo índice do for. Mas isso deixaria o código bem mais complexo. Todavia pode fazer uma nova pergunta com o código que já tem e conseguir ajuda para diminui-lo.

Comment: Esse código, nao funcionou no ipad, sabe me dizer pq?